# How to include initial conditions in the loop

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am currently doing a simulation of two moving circles and I can't seem to include the initial positions of the two circle. I would like to observe their behavior when they don't awlays start from the same position.

```
clc 
clear
close all

% Paramètres de la simulation
m1 = 1; % Masse du premier objet en kg,rouge
m2 =15 ; % Masse du deuxième objet en kg,bleu
k = 10 ; % Constante de raideur du ressort en N/m
L0 = 1; % Longueur à vide du ressort en m
x10 = 5; % Position initiale du premier objet en m
x20 = 0.5; % Position initiale du deuxième objet en m
y10 = 5; % Position initiale du premier objet en m
y20 = 0.5; % Position initiale du deuxième objet en m
v10 = 0; % Vitesse initiale du premier objet en m/s
v20 = 0; % Vitesse initiale du deuxième objet en m/s
tmax = 35; % Temps maximal de la simulation en s
dt = 0.1; % Pas de temps de la simulation en s

% Initialisation des variables
t = 0:dt:tmax; % Vecteur temps
n = length(t); % Nombre de pas de temps
x1 = zeros(n, 1); % Vecteur position du premier objet
x2 = zeros(n, 1); % Vecteur position du deuxième objet
y1 = zeros(n, 1); % Vecteur position du premier objet
y2 = zeros(n, 1); % Vecteur position du deuxième objet
v1 = zeros(n, 1); % Vecteur vitesse du premier objet
v2 = zeros(n, 1); % Vecteur vitesse du deuxième objet



% Distance maximale entre les objets
distance_max = 2.5; % Distance maximale entre les objets en mètres
C = [0 0]; 
% Conditions initiales
x1(1) = x10;
y1(1) = y10;
x2(1) = x20;
y2(1) = y20;
v1x(1) = v10;
v1y(1) = v10;

v2x(1) = v20;
v2y(1) = v20;

%Trajectoire cercle
x2 = C(1)+5*cos(0.2*t); % Cordonnées en x et y du cercle de centre C[0 0]
y2 = C(2)+5*sin(0.2*t);

%Trajectoire en 8
% x2 = 5*cos(0.2*t) ./ (1 + sin(0.2*t).^2); % Trajectoire en forme de signe de l'infini en x
% y2 = 5*sin(0.4*t) ./ (1 + sin(0.2*t).^2); % Trajectoire en forme de signe de l'infini en y

%Trajectoire signe ∞
% x2 = 5*cos(0.2*t) ./ (1 + sin(0.2*t).^2); % Trajectoire en forme de 8 en x
% y2 = 5*sin(0.4*t) .* cos(0.2*t) ./ (1 + sin(0.2*t).^2); % Trajectoire en forme de 8 en y

%x1 = 3*sin(0.4*t); %Position en x
%y1 = 3*sin(0.2*t); %Position en y 

crossing_threshold = 0.5; % Seuil de détection du croisement en mètres

% Initialisation de l'animation
figure;
axis([-10 10 -10 10]);
axis square;
hold on;
%plot([-2 2], [0 0], 'k'); % Dessine une ligne horizontale à y=0
obj1 = plot(x1(1), y1(1), 'ro', 'MarkerSize', 20, 'LineWidth', 2); % Dessine l'objet 1
obj2 = plot(x2(1), y2(1), 'bo', 'MarkerSize', 20, 'LineWidth', 2); % Dessine l'objet 2
spring = plot([x1(1) x2(1)], [y1(1) y2(1)], '--', 'LineWidth', 2); % Dessine le ressort

% Calcul des forces
L = sqrt((x2(1)-x1(1))^2 + (y2(1)-y1(1))^2 );
F = -k*(L0 - L); % Force exercée par le ressort en N
    F1x = F*((x2(1)-x1(1)))/L;
    F1y = F*(y2(1)-y1(1))/L;

    F2x = -F1x;
    F2y= - F1y;
    % Calcul des accélérations
    a1x = F1x/m1; % Accélération du premier objet en m/s^2
    a1y = F1y/m1; % Accélération du premier objet en m/s^2

    a2x = F2x/m2; % Accélération du deuxième objet en m/s^2
    a2y = F2y/m2; % Accélération du deuxième objet en m/s^2

% Boucle de simulation
for i = 2:n
    
  % % Vérification de la distance maximale
  %   distance = sqrt((x2(i)-x1(i))^2 + (y2(i)-y1(i))^2);
  %   if m1>=m2
  %       if distance > distance_max
  %           % Réduction de la distance entre les objets en ajustant leurs positions
  %           ratio = distance_max / distance;
  %           % x1(i) = x2(i) - (x2(i)- x1(i))* ratio;
  %           % y1(i) = y2(i) - (y2(i) - y1(i)) * ratio;
  %           % a2 = a2 +2;
  %           % v2(i) = v2(i-1)+ a2*dt;
  %           x2(i) = x1(i) - (x1(i) - x2(i) ) * ratio;
  %           y2(i) = y1(i) - (y1(i) - y2(i) ) * ratio;
  %       end
  %   else
  %       if distance > distance_max
  %           ratio = distance_max / distance;
  %           x1(i) = x2(i) - (x2(i)- x1(i))* ratio;
  %           y1(i) = y2(i) - (y2(i) - y1(i)) * ratio;
  %       end
  %   end  
  
    
    
% Calcul des vitesses et positions
v1x(i) = v1x(i-1) + a1x*dt; % Vitesse du premier objet à l'instant i en m/s
v1y(i) = v1y(i-1) + a1y*dt;

v2x(i) = v2x(i-1) + a2x*dt;
v2y(i) = v2y(i-1) + a2y*dt;




x1(i) = x1(i) + v1x(i)*dt; % Position du premier objet à l'instant i en m
y1(i) = y1(i) + v1y(i)*dt; % Position du premier objet à l'instant i en m

x2(i) = x2(i)+ v2x(i)*dt; % Position du deuxième objet à l'instant i en m
y2(i) = y2(i)+ v2y(i)*dt; % Position du deuxième objet à l'instant i en m

L = sqrt((x2(i)-x1(i))^2 + (y2(i)-y1(i))^2 );
F = -k*(L0 - L); 

    F1x = F*((x2(i-1)-x1(i-1)))/L;
    F1y = F*(y2(i-1)-y1(i-1))/L;

    F2x = -F1x;
    F2y= - F1y;
    
   
    % Calcul des accélérations
    a1x = F1x/m1; % Accélération du premier objet en m/s^2
    a1y = F1y/m1; % Accélération du premier objet en m/s^2

    a2x = F2x/m2; % Accélération du deuxième objet en m/s^2
    a2y = F2y/m2; % Accélération du deuxième objet en m/s^2
%L = sqrt((x2(i-1)-x1(i-1))^2 ); % Longueur du ressort en m


%Calcul de la position (x,y) de chaque utilisateur
 Pos1 = sqrt (round(x1,2).^2 + round(y1,2).^2);
 Pos2 = sqrt (round(x2,2).^2 + round(y2,2).^2).';

%disp(Pos1)
%Calcul de la distance séparant les deux utilisateurs
d(i)= sqrt((x1(i)-x2(i))^2+(y1(i)-y2(i))^2);


% Vérifier si la trajectoire de l'objet 1 croise la trajectoire de l'objet 2


% Affichage du résultat
plot(x2(1:i),y2(1:i),'b','LineWidth',2);hold on
plot(x1(1:i),y1(1:i),'r','LineWidth',2);hold on

set(obj1, 'XData', x1(i), 'YData', y1(i)); % Met à jour la position de l'objet 1
set(obj2, 'XData', x2(i), 'YData', y2(i)); % Met à jour la position de l'objet 2
set(spring, 'XData', [x1(i) x2(i)], 'YData', [y1(i) y2(i)]); % Met à jour la position du ressort
drawnow; % Met à jour la figure

grid on;


% Pause pour contrôler la vitesse de l'animation
pause(0.01);
end
```

The comments are in french but if you need clarifications, please feel free to tell me. Thank you for helping me.

I have tried to put (i-1) in the lines x(i) = x(i) + v(i)*dt; ( x(i) = x(i-1) + v(i)*dt). I was expecting it to work in order to include x(1).
Also I have tried to write :  v1x(i) = v1x(i-1) + a1x(i-1)*dt; instead of : v1x(i) = v1x(i-1) + a1x(i)*dt;
Both times,I get the error : Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1.

Comment: The error tells you exactly in which line it happens. Can you share that?

Comment: should this line `x1(i) = x1(i) + v1x(i)*dt;` instead be this `x1(i) = x1(i-1) + v1x(i)*dt;` (and the other similar lines)?

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you for your answer, the error tells me it's for the lines : v1x(i) = v1x(i-1) + a1x(i-1)*dt if I write a1x(i-x) instead of a1x(i) for example

Comment: @magnesium yes that is right, so I can use the initial position in the loop

Comment: Here is an full example of the error : Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 1.

Error in Test1 (line 263)
    v1x(i) = v1x(i-1) + a1x(i-1)*dt; % Vitesse du premier objet à l'instant i en m/s

Comment: well `v1x` has not been iniialized to an array, instead it is 1 number. `v1x(2)` should give you that error.

Comment: Not sure where you have gotten up to. But when you update the accelerations inside the for loop you should save them in an array (I think). So `a1x = F1x/m1` (INSIDE the loop) should instead be `a1x(i) = F1x/m1` etc etc.

Comment: Hi @magnesium, I have tried that but it doesn't seem to have an affect on me including the initial positions in the simulation loop. It starts at zero (approximately) even if I change the initial coordinates. Sorry for the late reply, I am still stuck with this so if you have any idea they are welcome thanks again.